# primefaces 3.2 - Can't auto focus the next field

Tags: primefaces

I encountered a strange problem, not sure if it is a bug. Basically, the focus will skip the next  if the current  update the next via ajax.

To duplicate the issue, you can use the below bean:

```
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
   private BigDecimal a;
   private BigDecimal b;
   private BigDecimal c;
   //
   public TestBean() {
   }
   public BigDecimal getA() {
      return a;
   }
   public void setA(BigDecimal a) {
      this.a = a;
   }
   public BigDecimal getB() {
      return b;
   }
   public void setB(BigDecimal b) {
      this.b = b;
   }
   public BigDecimal getC() {
      return c;
   }
   public void setC(BigDecimal c) {
      this.c = c;
      this.calculate();
   }
   public void calculate() {
      if (a != null && b != null)
      c = a.multiply(b);
   }
}
```

and the below xhtml

```
 <p:inputText id="a" value="#{testBean.a}" style="text-align:right">
    <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{testBean.calculate}" update="c d"/>
 </p:inputText>
 <p:inputText id="b" value="#{testBean.b}" style="text-align:right">
    <p:ajax event="blur" listener="#{testBean.calculate}" update="c d"/>
 </p:inputText>
 <p:inputText id="c" value="#{testBean.c}" style="text-align:right">
 </p:inputText>
 <p:inputText id="d" value="#{testBean.c}"/>
```

1. First of all, I'll click the field id="a", id="a" will gain focus, and I'll key in some value. No problem here.
2. Then I'll press the tab key to move the cursor to the next field, id = "b", and key in some value. No problem here.
3. Then I'll press the tab key again, expecting the cursor to move the next field, id = "c". But it doesn't happen. Only the value of the field id="c" is updated, focus is lost some where. While focus is missing, if I press the tab key again, focus will move to id = "a" (or the first field).
4. Even if I don't use the tab key and use mouse click instead, if I am at the field id = "b" now and do a click on id="c", focus will go missing too.
5. If I remove the "c" from the field id="b" update, making it update="d", then focus will rest on field id="c", but the problem is, it doesn't get updated with the calculated value of "c".

In conclusion, I believe I can say that if the current  field runs an ajax event to update the next  field via update="nextfield", then, the next  field cannot be focused via tab-key or the next mouse clicked. A second mouse click will bring the focus to the next  field but that is tedious. However, I can update all the fields after the immediate next field and still have focus rest correctly on the immediate next field.

Is this the way it supposed to be? How to actually bring the focus to the next field in this case?

(PrimeFaces 3.2)

Answer (score 0):

When the `update` happens, the HTML is renewed for `c` and `d`, so cursor cannot be focused on these elements.
Not sure you want to use some post event JavaScript to set the focus or just accept this behaviour.

Comment: I tried oncomplete, but it interferes with the oncomplete of the ajaxstatus...thanks for replying though...